# Delta function from a limit?

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm having trouble understanding how the delta function comes from a specific limit I encountered in [this article](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=152013104065027064082095065019017102101074051042007060126089029090123104127004075073055020029097121126020121083006097112011088059016075034036070003023100018120087080067045021074122026001076006071090070115024106126127121112070107094073106108083111125073&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE): at the end of page 5 and beginning of page 6 they give the following functions:
$$Q(x,y,\tau)=exp\Biggl(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\Sigma^2}\Biggr)$$
with $\mu=xe^{-b\tau}+\frac{a}{b}(1-e^{-b\tau})$ e $\Sigma^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{2b}(1-e^{-2b\tau})$ and
$$\phi(y,\tau)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2b\tau}}}$$
Then they claim that in order to fit to the intial condition for $f(x,y,\tau)=\phi(y,\tau)Q(x,y,\tau)$ that is $f(x,y,0)=\delta(x-y)$, one can do the limit of $f$ for $\tau$ that tends to $0$ and find the missing term that should be $(2\pi\sigma^2/(2b))^{-1/2}$ so that
$$f(x,y,\tau)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\Sigma}exp\Biggl(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{\Sigma^2}\Biggr)$$
I really don't understand how to get that term from the limit, can anyone explain this step?

Comment: From a decent family of functions $f(x,y,\tau)$ that "converges" to the delta "function" we expect that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y,\tau)\,dx=1$ for all $\tau>0$ and $\lim\limits_{\tau\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)f(x,y,\tau)\,dx=g(y)\,.$ That's exactly what that classic example $f(x,y,\tau)$ does.

Comment: oh so I need to impose this two conditions and not do a normal limit, right? If this is the case please write an answer and I'll accept it and close the question, thank you.

Comment: Depending on the level of rigor you are asking for that answer might just repeat standard stuff about [Schwartz distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). For practitioners in mathematical finance it is enough to know what we already wrote here.